# C++ to C# implementing

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

> A call to PInvoke function 'xxx' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

```
JSPRINTERDLL_API BOOL  _stdcall WriteUsb(HANDLE hUsb,char *SendBuf,DWORD SendBufSize,LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWriten);

[DllImport("JsPrinterDll.dll", PreserveSig = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, BestFitMapping = false, ExactSpelling = false)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool WriteUsb(
    IntPtr hUsb,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] 
    char[] SendBuf, 
    UInt32 SendBufSize, 
    UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWriten);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please don't just post the error and a bit of code.  Explain what the code is meant to do even if it is a function prototype.  Good luck!

Comment: Two mistakes that I can see. `SendBuf` looks more like `byte[]`, and you don't need a `MarshalAs` for it. And `lpNumberOfBytesWriten` should be `out UInt32`. I don't think that you need the MarshalAs on the return. And the DllImport should just be `[DllImport("JsPrinterDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]`

Comment: It would also be nice to know what `JSPRINTERDLL_API` is

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, I should have spent the time to read the unmanaged declaration!